# Grails 2.3.6 and Multi-Domain/Multi-Tenancy

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.6 with an nginx. We're extending our app to use multiple domains (web-addresses, not domain classes) with it.

The idea is to check the tld and assign the matching client from the database within a Filter beforeRender. So, therefore I removed config.serverUrl in the production config brackets, otherwise it'll auto-redirect.

So for, it works. But as soon as Grails performs a redirect or createLink(absolute: true), it'll redirect to {correctUrl}:80/myaction. But mostly, the app runs on 443.

**Possible ideas:**

- set the serverUrl depending on the web address/domain?
- override createLink and redirect?

I wasn't able to find this anywhere. Is there a solution? I'm using asset pipeline plugin 2.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it seems that NGINX is the problem. When setting the X-Forwarded-Port, it works.

Found at: [Grails spring security redirects to wrong port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871078/grails-spring-security-redirects-to-wrong-port)